# MVC 5 on IIS 8.5 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

i built and ran a brand new VS 2013 MVC5 project on IIS Express but when deploy to IIS 8.5 a have the error
**The ClaimsAuthorizationModule cannot be used without at least one other module such as a WSFederationAuthenticationModule, SessionAuthenticationModule or ClaimsPrincipalHttpModule.**

my webconfig is 
what am i missing?

```html
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString=""
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try to search on SO. This question seems to be answered

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new installation of IIS, or a new site on it, it could be an issue with the app pool.  If under advanced settings you haven't set the 'identity' to 'LocalService'

Steps:
Under advanced look under 'Generate Process Model Event Log Entry' then under there find 'identity' update the value to 'LocalService'

Let me know if this fixes your issue.  It was a bizarre one for me the first time i had it.

*Update:

I should have looked closer at your config. [How To: Build Claims-Aware ASP.NET MVC Web Application Using WIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  It goes over the steps to include and configure WIF

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
        <audienceUris>
            <add value="http://localhost:28503/" />
        </audienceUris>
        <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <trustedIssuers>
                <add thumbprint="1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234" name="YourSTSName" />
            </trustedIssuers> 
        </issuerNameRegistry>
        <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
    </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
<system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
        <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="http://localhost:13922/wsFederationSTS/Issue" realm="http://localhost:28503/" reply="http://localhost:28503/" requireHttps="false" />
    </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
```

Comment: I changed application pool identity to LocalService still got the same error so strange

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. Sorry Folks! there was something wrong with my IIS installation, i turned it off and turn it back on that problem went away. Sorry for the fuzz